# What is the advantage of having date as int?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We store date data as int instead if date formart with SQL server 2008.

Why they won't store date as date format type?
Is there any advantage?

Comment: Why don't you ask someone who decided to do that this way at your firm?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15645/storing-date-as-integer-numeric-what-are-the-advantages

Comment: btw. even when you use `datetime` column, it's internally stored as a number, as described [here](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2004/datetime-datatype/). But with the type you get a set of functions which know how to handle that number and return you some more interesting and user-friendly information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to SQL Server 2008 it was common (perhaps even best practice) to use integer encoded dates in warehouses, i.e. 20130106

It was storage efficient (4 bytes) and human readable.

Now that there is a (3 byte) `Date`  datatype, I would use that in new development.

(splitting date and time in either scheme is important to reduce the size of those respective dimensions in warehouses)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you would need to ask the people that put the guidelines/rules together to be certain. I, for one, would rather use the DBMS date formats since there are a lot of things you can do with them beyond simple comparisons, and in a way that's usually more efficient.

I seem to recall that versions of SQL Server prior to 2008 didn't actually *have* separate date and time data types so it may be a hangover from earlier code/data, or coders who haven't kept themselves current. The `datetime` types that *were* available also had other limitations such as timezone-unawareness.

Answer (score 1):

**First Advantage**

Storing date as integer has advantage of being Language Neutral for all date and time settings.
For example, the form 20070212 is always interpreted as ymd, regardless of your date setting being English , US, Japanese etc. type.

Consider a date being compared with string '02/12/07'.

```
SELECT *
FROM Sales.Orders
WHERE orderdate = '02/12/07';
```

This would be interpreted as  February 12, 2007, in US settings. However, if
For British, this form probably means December 2, 2007. For Japanese, it probably
means December 7, 2002.

So depending on language settings specified for particular SQL Server logon , the datetime column will interpret diffrently while filtering.

**Second Advantage**

While filtering records based on date column we sometimes need to apply functions on them to retrieve some datepart and compare.

```
SELECT *
FROM Sales.Orders
WHERE YEAR(orderdate) = 2007 AND MONTH(orderdate) = 2;
```

Applying functions on columns makes query slower and should be avoided as far as possible.
Now consider equivalent query if date was stored as integer

```
SELECT *
FROM Sales.Orders
WHERE orderdate >= 20070201
```

Notice no requirment to apply any function on orderdate column. This makes query faster.